# Convert string represented in scientific notation to float and double

Tags: c++, data-conversion

So I am working on this project where I have to read in a CSV file which contains numbers that are represented in scientific notation.  So far what I have is to read in each number then convert that number into string then convert it to double with stringstream but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it.  Any advice / suggestion would be helpful!

```
double temp;
istringstream in(line); //line is the string which contains the number, ex: 3.30144800e+03
in >> temp;
arr[w++] = temp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a string to a double with `std::atof`

```
istringstream in(line);
double        value(atof(in.str().c_str()));
```

OR you can simply stream the double out of the buffer...

```
double value;
in >> value;
```

Comment: I would recommend `strtod` (or C++11 `stod`), both of which let you see if the entire string was consumed to verify that there wasn't a parse error.